# I asked Allah to give me a good muslim husband and I dreamt a man that I know. Is there a connection? What that dream means?

Tags: nikah, dream

I would like to know is this dream from Allah because the night before I dreamt I truly asked Allah to give me a good husband. I tried so hard to understand.